# Using SUMIFS Function or Alternative Across Multiple Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

Let's say that I have the following in an Excel spreadsheet, in the same row:

```
joe hs  12  joe college 234 joe hs  12
```

My objective was to use a `SUMIFS` function that parses through each column, identifies whether or not "hs" appears, and, if that condition is met, adds the number following it. In this case, the sum would appear as 24.

I tried doing this using SUMIFS, but hit a wall. I then tried implementing the following array formula:

`{=SUM(IF((B1:B1="hs")+(E1:E1="hs")+(H1:H1="hs")),A1:I1,0)}`

This returned `#VALUE!`, and I don't understand why.

Any help would be deeply appreciated. I checked around, but have not been able to find an example that matches my dilemma.

Comment: `sumifs` is not an array formula.

Comment: You have the `)` out of place; `=SUM(IF((B1:B1="hs")+(E1:E1="hs")+(H1:H1="hs"),A1:I1))` This is an array so Ctrl-Shift-Enter

Comment: Can you expand on how your table is structured? Is it only 1 row with 3 columns, is it multiple rows with 3 columns or is it only 1 row with multiple columns?

Comment: It's one row with 9 columns. Each of the above terms occupies 1 cell of the same row.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the data you have is in A1:I1, you can use

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:I1="hs")*1,B1:J1)
```